# php copy() closes connection when copying multiple files

Tags: php

I'm trying to copy five large files using the copy() function in PHP, however, when I try to copy the files simultaneously, only the last file proceeds to copy while the other four stop abruptly.

```
<?php


$path_to_large_file_1 = 'http://very_large_file.zip';
$newfile_1 = '/home/username/public_html/files/file1.zip';

copy($path_to_large_file_1, $newfile_1);



$path_to_large_file_2 = 'http://very_large_file.zip';
$newfile_2 = '/home/username/public_html/files/file2.zip';

copy($path_to_large_file_2, $newfile_2);




$path_to_large_file_3 = 'http://very_large_file.zip';
$newfile_3 = '/home/username/public_html/files/file3.zip';

copy($path_to_large_file_3, $newfile_3);




$path_to_large_file_4 = 'http://very_large_file.zip';
$newfile_4 = '/home/username/public_html/files/file4.zip';

copy($path_to_large_file_4, $newfile_4);




$path_to_large_file_5 = 'http://very_large_file.zip';
$newfile_5 = '/home/username/public_html/files/file5.zip';

copy($path_to_large_file_5, $newfile_5);




?>
```

Comment: The is procedural so they all go in order. You are using the same file name so I'd guess it just over writes.. although I'm surprised `http://very_large_file.zip` is a valid name.

Comment: http://very_large_file.zip isn't an actual URL, it only represents a url that leads to a very large zip file. Kindly elaborate what you mean by 'procedural' since initially, they all start copying simultaneously however the four files come to a sudden halt when the last file starts to copy

Comment: Ah, I inverted the parameters. Your error logs have nothing in them? This should execute line 1, then line 2 etc. For a rough example https://3v4l.org/ir6hF. Try putting inverted `if`s around your `copy`s and do a `die` if/when it fails.

Comment: Error log is empty. The code seems to work as it should but the last file is prioritized while the previous files halt the copying process.